# Is there a method to sample number of rows randomly while two of those rows are constant

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I want to select a certain amount of rows randomly while the first and last samples are always selected.
Suppose I have a row of numbers `df` as

```
| A  | B |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1    | 10            |
| 2  | 158            |
| 3   | 106            |
| 4  | 155            |
| 5    | 130            |
| 6  | 154            |
| 7    | 160            |
| 8  | 157            |
| 9    | 140            |
| 10  | 158            |
| 11    | 210            |
| 12 | 157            |
| 13   | 140            |
| 14  | 156            |
| 15    | 160            |
| 16  | 135            |
| 17    | 102            |
| 18  | 150            |
| 19    | 120            |
| 20  | 12         |
```

From the table, I want to randomly select **5 rows**. While selecting 5 rows I want the **row 1** and **row 20** to be always selected, while the rest of 3 rows can be anything else.

Right now I'm doing the following thing, but don't know if there is a way to do it in the way I want.

```
n <- 5
shuffled= df[sample(1:nrow(df)), ] #shuffles the entire dataframe
extracted <- shuffled[1:n, ] #extracts top 5 rows from the shuffled sample
```

I need to do this because I will further analyze the results.

Comment: why not `df[ c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1)), 3), nrow(df) ), ]`

Comment: Hi I tired this ```df<- data.frame(rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 1))
a<- df[ c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1)), 3), nrow(df) , ]``` 
The result is ```a``` is null.

Comment: Looks like you have a missing closing parenthesis after the last `nrow(df)`

Comment: When the parenthesis was included it showed an error. So I had to delete it.

Comment: My error, extra paren. Try: `df[ c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1), 3), nrow(df) ), ]`

Comment: Sorry Nevermind, I got it

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

shuffle <- function(df, size, fixed = integer()) {
  
  i <- 1:nrow(df)
  ii <- i[-fixed]
  
  df[c(fixed, sample(ii, size)), ]
  
}

shuffle(starwars, 3, fixed = c(1, 2))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 14
#>   name         height  mass hair_…¹ skin_…² eye_c…³ birth…⁴ sex   gender homew…⁵
#>   <chr>         <int> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 Luke Skywal…    172  77   blond   fair    blue         19 male  mascu… Tatooi…
#> 2 C-3PO           167  75   <NA>    gold    yellow      112 none  mascu… Tatooi…
#> 3 Luminara Un…    170  56.2 black   yellow  blue         58 fema… femin… Mirial 
#> 4 R4-P17           96  NA   none    silver… red, b…      NA none  femin… <NA>   
#> 5 Mon Mothma      150  NA   auburn  fair    blue         48 fema… femin… Chandr…
#> # … with 4 more variables: species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
#> #   starships <list>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​hair_color, ²​skin_color,
#> #   ³​eye_color, ⁴​birth_year, ⁵​homeworld
#> # ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. The other solution works too. I have to see which one is useful for me. Thanks.